# Experiencing strange behaviour with cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I was setting up this application in cakephp.I have homes controller which works well and then i have chokates controller which has an index action.But whenever i run this chokates controller i get an error

> Call to a member function charset() on a non-object
>   I had a print of $this in top of this controller which shows me that html and javascript helpers are loaded already.Then why i get this error i dont know.

Please help
Here is the link http://www.maninactionscript.com/chokate
go to the chocolates link.

Regards
Himanshu Sharma

Answer (score 3):

Well, looking at your error message it appears that a couple things are happening here that should be fixed:

> The view for `ChokateController::index()` was not found.

Ensure that you have an `index.ctp` file in `/app/views/chokate/`.

The `HtmlHelper` object likely isn't being added to the view because you have a manually configured list of `$helpers`.  If you have assigned an array to `$helpers` in `ChokateController` ensure that `Html` is listed.

Comment: Thanx for your advivce Charles,
It turn out to be that i have not referenced html helper as Html in app controller,It was in small case like html that was causing the problem.